# JFrame.getLocationOnScreen() for minimized window

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I call [`getLocationOnScreen()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocationOnScreen%28%29) from `JFrame` in my Swing application. If `JFrame` is minimized -32000, -32000 is returned.

It is expected:

[Location Coordinates On Computer Showing X=-32000, Y=-32000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478765/location-coordinates-on-computer-showing-x-32000-y-32000)

But I need to know the location of the window before it was minimized or would be the location if it is maximized again without actual maximizing it. Because I need to position `JDialog` relatively to the `JFrame` even though it is minimized.

**Possible solution:**
Add `WindowListener` to `JFrame` and on `windowIconified()` event save the coordinates. And then use it instead of `getLocationOnScreen()`.

Is there better solution using only `JFrame` methods?

Multiscreen configuration is expected and the following code is used.

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();
    for (int j = 0; j < gs.length; j++) {
        GraphicsDevice gd = gs[j];
        GraphicsConfiguration[] gc = gd.getConfigurations();
        for (int i = 0; i < gc.length; i++) {
            Rectangle gcBounds = gc[i].getBounds();
            Point loc = topContainer.getLocationOnScreen(); //might return -32000 when minimized
            if (gcBounds.contains(loc)) { //fails if -32000 is returned
```

Comment: again for two or more screens?, or from single display mode :-)

Comment: @mKorbel, yes, multiscreen. I have updated with code. I use `gcBounds.contains(loc)` and it fails if `JFrame` is minimized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use `getLocation()`. Minimized or not, it will always return the appropriate value:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestJFrame {

    public void initUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestJFrame.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.err.println(frame.getLocation());
            }
        }, 0, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestJFrame().initUI();
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works for `JFrame`. I think `getLocation` was in use before. But it was failing for `topContainer` being JApplet, so I changed it to `getLocationOnScreen`.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Not an expert with applet, but as far as I could test it, it does not cause major issues to use `SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(TestApplet.this).getLocation()`