# Sending keys to inactive windows

Tags: java

I've been doing java for a couple months now in a software engineering class and I've recently been working on a program that sends text to an inactive or minimized program. Sending it to the active window is a simple matter of importing jna and using the key press function, ex: `r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F6);`. However, I can't find out how to set the handler to the minimized window and then send the keys there.

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438539/jframe-getlocationonscreen-for-minimized-window

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I was talking about minimized Microsoft windows applications not JFrame.