# WindowFromPoint in minimized windows

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently, I use folowing code to find window from point on my desktop

```
var p = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;
var h = WindowFromPoint(p.X, p.Y);
Thread.Sleep(10);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(255);
GetWindowText(h, sb, 255);
MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```

But now I want to get windows from point related to a windows, because I want to get it even owned window minimized or normal state.
Thanks.

Comment: First of all, you should _never_ do a Thread.Sleep() on the UI thread of a WinForms program. That is always an indication of lack of understanding about how Windows and WinForms work. If you need to pause the processing then use a WinForms Timer.

Comment: Next, I'm not sure I understand your question, but this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1478980/253938